# How does distance between wings of a biplane affect its horizontal stabilizer design?

Tags: aerodynamics, stability, horizontal-stabilizer, biplane

When for instance pitching down, a biplane's upper wing has higher airspeed than lower wing, therefore higher drag that should dampen the pitching down rate.

How significant is this, if it is, regarding horizontal stabilizer design?